# Using dimensional analysis to find the expression for free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, dimensional-analysis

In page 181 of Thomas Hartman's [notes](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/gravity-lectures.pdf) on Quantum Gravity and Black Holes, we have the following:

The thermodynamic free energy $F$ is given by

$$F = - T \log Z,$$

where $Z$ is the partition function.

This can be computed by the Euclidean path integral on $R^{d-1} \times S_{\beta}^{1}$.

At a fixed point, dimensional analysis fixes

$$F(\beta) = - c_{\text{therm}}V_{d-1}T^{d}$$

where $c_{\text{therm}}$ is a dimensionless number.

---

How does dimensional analysis fix the free energy to be

$$F(\beta) = - c_{\text{therm}}V_{d-1}T^{d}$$

at a fixed point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free energy is an extensive quantity, so it must scale with the volume.  Since we are in $d-1$ spatial dimensions, it makes sense to label the volume as $V_{d-1}$. In natural units $\hbar=c=k_B=1$ the dimensions of length are the same as the inverse units of energy, $[L]=[E]^{-1}$. Therefore a $d-1$-dimensional volume has dimensions of $[V_{d-1}]=[L]^{d-1}=[E]^{1-d}$.

The free energy is an energy, so it must have dimensions of energy.  The only dimensionful scale in the problem (other than the volume) is the temperature, $T$.  In natural units $[T]=[E]$. Therefore we must have that $F=c V_{d-1}T^d$, where $c$ is some dimensionless number.